# PHP database user selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, authentication

Alright, so I have setup a very simple login in and sign up database, it is working perfectly.

However, one of the page I have created where users can check their acccount information (Username and Email) is not working fully.

I have a database that has four columns ID, username, email and password.

All I am doing is taking the user information from the database (Who is logged in) and displaying their username and email on the page.

The problem is that the code is logging every user within the database, I only want it to select one user (The user that is logged in.)

Code:

```
<?php
// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

   // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
  echo $row['email'] . "<br />";
  echo $_SESSION['username'];

  }

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

I'm thankful for the help !

Comment: Note: Please use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` because it is deprecated and soon to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query should look something like this...

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = '$user_id'"
```

Remember to fix any SQL vulnerabilities

```
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to store the `username` value in a `$_SESSION` in your login session.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = the_id_of_your_logged_username;
}
```

Then using the value that is stored in the `$_SESSION` to retrieve the logged user.

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
```

In these way, you can retrieve the logged user, just commonly on how users login and gets their profile directly.

Comment: Seems legit, I'll test.

Comment: You could search more about `$_SESSION` and other global variables.

Comment: I think I have nearly got it, the trouble is I do not know what to put in the $_SESSION['id'] = the_id_of_your_logged_username; line. If I put in a id value of 2, it will log the second row in the database, that's not the aim, I want the code to recognize which user logged in then display their data.

Comment: I have added, echo $_SESSION['username']; And it works perfectly. However, if i try to display their email with echo $_SESSION['email']; I get an error of Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\registeration\registeration\Account.php

Comment: Try adding a `session_start()`.